# Database ERD, potential loop issues?

Tags: database, erd

Currently working on a CMS for a nature heritage site, just wanted to get some feedback on the database ERD for a particular section that deals with photos.

I have a table called Species which has records of different plant species. Linked to this is populations which basically track the areas a species can be found, then sightings basically records every time someone physically goes out and looks at that population to make notes of health, changes etc.

Linked to all that is media, which will basically be a table containing hashed links to photos stored on the cloud. The photos need to have information on what species has been photographed, but we also want to know when and where that photograph was taken, hence the need to link it back to the sighting event. Here's the subsection of the ERD highlighting the loop.

[image]

I just want to know, is this loop going to potentially cause issues? I know I could potentially remove the link from Media to Species and have that reference linked via sightings only, however I want to make this conductive to machine learning later on (basically to analyse a new photo  against the photo repository to identify what species has been photographed). I'm assuming that it would be expensive in terms of processing time if it had to go through 2 other tables to get the entire list of photos for a particular species to then analyse for example.

Is that a valid assumption?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any loops / cyclic dependencies. What you have is two paths by which Species can be determined from Media. A direct functional dependency:

```
mediaID -> speciesID
```

As well as a transitive functional dependency:

```
mediaID -> sightID -> popID -> speciesID
```

The risk here is inconsistency. A bug in your program (or an incorrect manual entry) may end up recording different species for a given media via the two paths. Ideally, we would like to record each fact only once and have the DBMS ensure the validity of our data.

Your assumption isn't necessarily correct. Database management systems have numerous mechanisms to speed up joins, like indexes. Exactly how efficient or inefficient a join query would be depends on many factors, like the specific DBMS, the volume of records you expect in your various tables, the indexes you create, and the particular query you use to retrieve the data.

I suggest you remove the redundant attribute for now. It's easy enough to reintroduce it later and populate it via a suitable query, if you see that the join query can't be optimized sufficiently. If you keep (or reintroduce) the redundant attribute, it's possible to enforce consistency using things like triggers or foreign key constraints. Alternatively, a nightly script to update the redundant attribute could help to prevent inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can break the loop between species and media, hence you only need to know
the sighting, and that will lead to get the population and then you will get species, but if you broke any other relationships you will get traps like the fan trap if you broke the link between **population** and *sighting*